# Remove unwanted characters from URL

Tags: regex, seo, url-routing

I have used GetRouteUrl to create SEO friendly URLs but I now want to remove %20 ie spaces and replace with a dash ("-"). An example page from my website is shown below. I want to Title variable to be "madonna-item" and not "Madonna%20Item".

> /ProductsByDepartment/Gracya/Madonna/Madonna%20Item?CategoryId=9&productId=8&departmentId=4

I have create a class (StringHelpers) to fix the url but I don't know where to call FixUrl

```
Public static class StringHelpers 
{

public static string FixUrl(this string url)
    {
        string encodedUrl = (url ?? "").ToLower();

        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"\+", "and");

        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Replace("'", "");

        encodedUrl = Regex.Replace(encodedUrl, @"[^a-z0-9]", "-");

        return encodedUrl;
    }
```

}

The code which contains the link to update is below. I want to use FixUrl on the Title field, but this does not work.

**Please can you advise me how to use FixUrl?**

```
<td class="Product_title" height="20px" width="180px">
<a href='<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductExtraRoute", new {CategoryId = Eval("catId"), productId = Eval("productId"), departmentId = Eval("depId"), Title = Eval("Title")}).FixUrl()%>' class="Product">
<asp:Literal ID="literal2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(("Title").FixUrl()) %>'></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try decodeURIComponent
Check this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

After this replace all speces with -

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Please can you advise how the decodeURIComponent could be used in my example above? Does the javascript code get added to the .aspx code so that it amends the url at runtime?